# How to include external html page

Tags: html

I am developing a website , I have an html page which has some contents, have also made a signUp modal in the same page, but the code is getting longer, I just want to know if I keep the code of sign up modal in another file with .html/.htm extension, and on button click that modal is displayed on the same page, not to be redirected to another page, like it is displaying on the home.
I don't want the home contents to be shattered , just the modal to be displayed on above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery to accomplish this task:

Just create a new file "modal.html" and write code for popup there.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("modal.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
 <div id="header"></div>
 <!-- other code -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use w3data and include your file where ever you want. In blow i included signup.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

    <body>
        <div w3-include-html="signup.html"></div> 
        <script>
            w3IncludeHTML();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JoshCrowe That's possible too

Answer (score 1):

Simple Method  to load Html File to main

```
$(function(){
      $('#which').load('test.html');
});
```

you can write inside document.ready also

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an `iframe` (inline frame) to load the external webpage. You can style the size of the `iframe` like you normally would with any HTML element.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="/your-signup-page.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

[More information on the `iframe` element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)